# How to use CR2032 button cells for excitation of load cell

Tags: batteries, button, load

I am using a load cell that required 9-12V excitation voltage. Can I use a few, say 4 CR2032 button cells to generate 4x3V=12V of excitation voltage for the load cell?

I could also use a 9V batter. But my problem is that the battery goes down and that affects the accuracy of the load cell output.

Answer (score 1):

CR2032 cells have quite high internal resistance. Any decrease in voltage due to the load will only be worse with stack of CR2032 cells.

You need a voltage regulator, not a better kind of battery. For example, if the end-of-life voltage of your 9V cell is ~6V you could use two in series and a regulator to give you 12V.

Comment: How long do you think would 2 9V battery last if they are powering just a load cell?

Comment: You can work it out- depends on the resistance of the load cell and how much current the regulator draws for itself, and the mA-h capacity of the cell. If it's 400 ohms it will draw 30mA so a good & fresh alkaline 9V battery pair might last 10 hours. A single 9V battery of similar capacity would last ~2x *longer* if you regulated it down to 6V (but you'd have half the signal).

Comment: That's the problem. I thought CR2032's last longer than 10-20 hours. I could use a 7809 to regulate 18V from 2x9V alkaline batteries. But you say they won't last more than 4-5 days (assuming ~400 ohms of load cell resistance) Can you please suggest a power source that could last longer than that? I have seen kitchen weigh scales run on batteries and last for months. What could they be using?

Comment: They don't run all the time. If you run for 30 seconds at at time twice a day, 10 hours is a couple years.

Comment: thanks so much for your valuable help. I think I need to figure out a way to put my thing into power save mode so that it comes on only for a minute each day to weigh and then goes back to sleep. That it, I would be happy even if lasts couple of years. Can you please suggest any power saving circuits?

Comment: You can use a regulator with a shutdown input. Usually they'll just draw a small number of uA when in shutdown- less than the self-discharge of a battery.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a step-up DC/DC converter. It will suck your batteries to dry and deliver best efficiency possible. And regulation of course. And it will work the same with one or two or three cells. Just pick one with small quiescent current.

Comment: Thanks Gregory! I don't think I have the budget for a step-up DC to DC converter. So purely on the basis of cost to benefit ratio, it looks like this won't work for me on this project.

Comment: Why, what is the budget? It can be done for like $1, comparable with the coin cells. And i don't believe you have quantity that would justify something cheap but ineffective.